# Android fragments appearing in the background

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I have got a problem regarding android fragments. I have 3 fragments say A, B and C. From A I move to B and I have an if statement that checks a value from shared preferences if value exists it move to C. If i press back button on Fragment C, it navigates to Fragment A but fragment C is also visible in background. Don`t know how to fix it. I have tried almost every solution from SO questions. 
Here is my code 
In fragment A on button click

```
Fragment fragment = new MyAccount();
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).addToBackStack(null)
.commit();
```

In fragment B

```
if(RegDetails.contains("MSISDN")&&RegDetails.contains("PIN")){
            Fragment fragment = new ReferFriend();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment)
            .commit();
        }
```

From B it move to c and works fine. But when I click back button on C fragment A is visible but fragment C is also visible in background.

Comment: Not the problem in this instance, but I had a problem with fragments remaining visible - then I found that I was using `.replace(R.id.container,...` for one fragment and `.replace(R.id.content,...` for another. Doh!

Answer (score 0):

I see two options:

- Add a solid background (color) to your A-fragment's root view
- Use `.show()` and `.hide()`